# Controlador sobre cargado con consultas?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Tengo una duda. Actualmente tengo un controlador que se encarga básicamente de recopilar información de dos tablas de la bd y mostrar la información en una tabla de tipo . Estos valores pueden llegar a sumarse entre si o restarse. Estos valores son mas de 50 y para cada uno estoy haciendo una consulta.

Se que esta no es la mejor manera de hacerlo y me gustaría saber de que otra forma lo puedo hacer.

Para que puedan ver a lo que me refiero, esta es solamente una parte del método del controlador:

```
public function show_it1 (Request $request)
{

    // Busca el cliente enviado en el formulario y examina los datos
    $cliente = Cliente::find($request->get('cliente_id'));

    // Filtro de busqueda de las facturas 606
    $reporte606 = Factura::cliente_id($request->get('cliente_id'))
    ->tiempo($tiempo = Carbon::parse ($request->get('tiempo')))
    ->where('tipo_factura', '=', '606')
    ->select('documento', 'bienes', 'ncf', 'ncf_modificado','date_comp', 'date_pago',
            'tipo_bien', 'monto_servicios', 'monto_bienes',  'monto_total',  'itebis_fact',
            'itebis_retenido', 'itebis_sujeto', 'itebis_costo', 'itebis_adelantar', 'itebis_compras',
                'tipo_retencion', 'monto_retenido', 'isr', 'impuesto_consumo', 'otros_impuestos',
                'propina', 'forma_pago' )
    ->orderBy('created_at' ,'ASC')
    ->get();

    // Filtro de busqueda de las facturas 607
    $reporte607 = Factura::cliente_id($request->get('cliente_id'))
    ->tiempo($tiempo = Carbon::parse ($request->get('tiempo')))
    ->where('tipo_factura', '=', '607')
    ->select('documento','tipo_documento', 'ncf', 'ncf_modificado', 'tipo_ingreso','date_comp', 'date_pago',
            'date_reten', 'monto_fact', 'itebis_fact',  'itebis_retenido',  'itbis_perci',
            'reten_renta', 'isr', 'impuesto_consumo', 'otros_impuestos', 'propina',
             'efectivo', 'ctd', 'tarjeta', 'venta_credito', 'bonos', 'permuta', 'ofv' )
    ->orderBy('created_at' ,'ASC')
    ->get();

    // Fecha limite y fecha de pago son calculados
    $periodo = $tiempo->format('yym');// Periodo en que se presentan las facturas
    $fecha_limite = $tiempo->addMonth(); // Feca limite de pago
    $tipo_declaracion = $request->get('tipo_declaracion'); // Tipo de declaracion

    //-------------------------------- Valores de la seccion II---------------------------
    // Busca los comprobantes B01 para llenar la fila 1
    $fila1 = Factura::cliente_id($request->get('cliente_id'))
    ->tiempo($tiempo = Carbon::parse ($request->get('tiempo')))
    ->where('tipo_factura', '=', '607')
    ->where('ncf', 'like', 'B01%')
    ->get();
    // Obtiene el monto
    $fila1_monto = $fila1->sum('monto_fact');
    //Obtiene la cantidad
    $fila1_cantidad = $fila1->count();
    // Estos dos valores se envian a la vista del anexo 1
```

Otra parte del código.

```
 // Obtiene el monto
    $fila1_monto = $fila1->sum('monto_fact');
    //Obtiene la cantidad
    $fila1_cantidad = $fila1->count();
    // Estos dos valores se envian a la vista del anexo 1

    // Busca los comprobantes B02 para llenar la fila 2
    $fila2 = Factura::cliente_id($request->get('cliente_id'))
    ->tiempo($tiempo = Carbon::parse ($request->get('tiempo')))
    ->where('tipo_factura', '=', '607')
    ->where('ncf', 'like', 'B02%')
    ->get();
    // Obtiene el monto
    $fila2_monto = $fila2->sum('monto_fact');
    //Obtiene la cantidad
    $fila2_cantidad = $fila2->count();
    // Estos dos valores se envian a la vista del anexo 1

    // Busca los comprobantes B03 para llenar la fila 3
    $fila3 = Factura::cliente_id($request->get('cliente_id'))
    ->tiempo($tiempo = Carbon::parse ($request->get('tiempo')))
    ->where('tipo_factura', '=', '607')
    ->where('ncf', 'like', 'B03%')
    ->get();
    // Obtiene el monto
    $fila3_monto = $fila3->sum('monto_fact');
    //Obtiene la cantidad
    $fila3_cantidad = $fila3->count();
    // Estos dos valores se envian a la vista del anexo 1
    
    // Busca los comprobantes B03 para llenar la fila 4
    $fila4 = Factura::cliente_id($request->get('cliente_id'))
    ->tiempo($tiempo = Carbon::parse ($request->get('tiempo')))
    ->where('tipo_factura', '=', '607')
    ->where('ncf', 'like', 'B04%')
    ->get();
    // Obtiene el monto
    $fila4_monto = $fila4->sum('monto_fact');
    //Obtiene la cantidad
    $fila4_cantidad = $fila4->count();
```

Comment: Exactamente.Asi es.

Comment: Si, siempre las voy a usar.

Comment: Acabo de editar la pregunte y añadí otra parte de mi codigo, basicamente lo que hago para resolver el problema es hacer todas las consultas que son necesarias y los mando todos a la vista.